# Get term value from referenced node

Tags: theming

Drupal 8 Twig
I have a content, which have entity reference field `field_field_data_provider_ref`, referencing another content, which itself contains a field field `buisness_property_type` (single taxonomy term)

```
 {{ node.field_field_data_provider_ref.entity.buisness_property_type.value }}

 {{ node.field_field_data_provider_ref.entity.buisness_property_type|views }}
```

doesn't work for me

Comment: Are you sure, that you are using right field name? You can inspect it with the devel or twig_vardumper module using `dump(node.field_field_data_provider_ref.entity)`. More about debugging twig templates: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates#s-viewing-variables

Comment: You spelt the word "buisness" wrong, its "business"

Comment: Does the entity reference get you the entity? Though you'd just get the entity ID...

Comment: This what i got only - target_id , this is sufficient for me now, but I would like also to know how to get a name for it.

Answer (score 0):

If the referenced field is a taxonomy term, you need to specify what property to show (usually the name). So your solution should be like

```
{{ node.field_field_data_provider_ref.entity.buisness_property_type.name.value }}
```

or, as NoSssweat said, with correct spelling (check your fieldnames)

```
{{ node.field_field_data_provider_ref.entity.business_property_type.name.value }}
```

also, I assume your machine name is field_business_property_type, so its

```
{{ node.field_field_data_provider_ref.entity.field_business_property_type.name.value }}
```

also, your field field_field_data_provider_ref is named field_data_provider_ref, then it's

```
{{ node.field_data_provider_ref.entity.field_business_property_type.name.value }}
```

Check your field names!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get target_id only , there is no .name in array for this field

```
{{ node.field_field_data_provider_ref.entity.field_buisness_property_type.target_id }}
```

Also , this works only with page--node.html.twig , but I need it within region.html.twig ( here it returns nothing)